# printing out an entire dictionary after it has been altered through a for loop (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to write a code that will eventually be implemented to encrypt text using a Caesar cipher. In this portion, I am trying to create (for any shift) a new dictionary that maps the original letter to the shifted letter (where uppercase -> uppercase and lowercase -> lowercase, and punctuation, numbers, and spaces stay the same.)

In the following code, I start with a dictionary mapping all letters (upper- and lowercase) to themselves, then alter it according to the shift:

```
def buildCoder(shift):
    """
    Returns a dict that can apply a Caesar cipher to a letter.
    The cipher is defined by the shift value. Ignores non-letter characters
    like punctuation, numbers, and spaces.

    shift: 0 <= int < 26
    returns: dict
    """
    import string
    mydict = {'A':'A','B':'B','C':'C','D':'D','E':'E','F':'F','G':'G','H':'H','I':'I','J':'J','K':'K','L':'L','M':'M','N':'N','O':'O','P':'P','Q':'Q','R':'R','S':'S','T':'T','U':'U','V':'V','W':'W','X':'X','Y':'Y','Z':'Z','a':'a','b':'b','c':'c','d':'d','e':'e','f':'f','g':'g','h':'h','i':'i','j':'j','k':'k','l':'l','m':'m','n':'n','o':'o','p':'p','q':'q','r':'r','s':'s','t':'t','u':'u','v':'v','w':'w','x':'x','y':'y','z':'z'} 
    newdict = {}
    for value in mydict:
        if value in string.ascii_uppercase:
            valIndex = string.ascii_uppercase.find(value)
            newVal = string.ascii_uppercase[((valIndex + shift) % 26)]
            newdict.update({str(value):str(newVal)})
            return newdict
        elif value in string.ascii_lowercase:
            valIndex = string.ascii_lowercase.find(value)
            newVal = string.ascii_lowercase[((valIndex + shift) % 26)]
            newdict.update({str(value):str(newVal)})
            return newdict
    return newdict
```

But my output looks like this:

```
buildCoder(3)
Out[7]: {'B': 'E'}
```

How can I get the program to print the entire shifted dictionary? And why is it only printing the value of B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are only doing the shift for the first letter then returning the dictionary, thats when the program exits your function. You don't need that return statement:

```
import string

def buildCoder(shift):
mydict = {'A':'A','B':'B','C':'C','D':'D','E':'E','F':'F','G':'G','H':'H','I':'I','J':'J','K':'K','L':'L','M':'M','N':'N','O':'O','P':'P','Q':'Q','R':'R','S':'S','T':'T','U':'U','V':'V','W':'W','X':'X','Y':'Y','Z':'Z','a':'a','b':'b','c':'c','d':'d','e':'e','f':'f','g':'g','h':'h','i':'i','j':'j','k':'k','l':'l','m':'m','n':'n','o':'o','p':'p','q':'q','r':'r','s':'s','t':'t','u':'u','v':'v','w':'w','x':'x','y':'y','z':'z'} 
for value in mydict:
    if value in string.ascii_uppercase:
        valIndex = string.ascii_uppercase.find(value)
        newVal = string.ascii_uppercase[((valIndex + shift) % 26)]
        newdict[value] = newVal
    elif value in string.ascii_lowercase:
        valIndex = string.ascii_lowercase.find(value)
        newVal = string.ascii_lowercase[((valIndex + shift) % 26)]
        newdict[value] = newVal
return newdict
```

Also, see how updating vales in a dict works in python, it's far easier to read.

Comment: then why does it shift 'B' and not, say 'A', or even 'b'? I know dictionaries are unsorted, but how did it choose?
And how can I get it to go through all of the values?

Comment: in Python, dictionary do not mantain the order of insertion or any specific order, since the accesing element is a key and not a fixed position.

Answer (score 1):

```
def buildCoder(shift):    
    idx = shift % 26
    mapping = dict(zip(ascii_lowercase,ascii_lowercase[idx:] + ascii_lowercase));
    mapping.update(dict(zip(ascii_uppercase,ascii_uppercase[idx:] + ascii_uppercase)))
    return mapping
```

is much cleaner

Comment: Should be `zip(ascii_lowercase, asci_lowercase[shift % 26:] + ascii_lowercase[:shift % 26])` (and similarly for uppercase) or you're going to omit a lot of characters.

Comment: there fixed :) thanks :P actually taking advantage of zips truncation i dont need to say [:shift] for the second argument

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried this one but it should work. It's the returns.

```
def buildCoder(shift):
    """
    Returns a dict that can apply a Caesar cipher to a letter.
    The cipher is defined by the shift value. Ignores non-letter characters
    like punctuation, numbers, and spaces.

    shift: 0 <= int < 26
    returns: dict
    """
    import string
    mydict = {'A':'A','B':'B','C':'C','D':'D','E':'E','F':'F','G':'G','H':'H','I':'I','J':'J','K':'K','L':'L','M':'M','N':'N','O':'O','P':'P','Q':'Q','R':'R','S':'S','T':'T','U':'U','V':'V','W':'W','X':'X','Y':'Y','Z':'Z','a':'a','b':'b','c':'c','d':'d','e':'e','f':'f','g':'g','h':'h','i':'i','j':'j','k':'k','l':'l','m':'m','n':'n','o':'o','p':'p','q':'q','r':'r','s':'s','t':'t','u':'u','v':'v','w':'w','x':'x','y':'y','z':'z'} 
    newdict = {}
    for value in mydict:
        if value in string.ascii_uppercase:
            valIndex = string.ascii_uppercase.find(value)
            newVal = string.ascii_uppercase[((valIndex + shift) % 26)]
            newdict.update({str(value):str(newVal)})
        elif value in string.ascii_lowercase:
            valIndex = string.ascii_lowercase.find(value)
            newVal = string.ascii_lowercase[((valIndex + shift) % 26)]
            newdict.update({str(value):str(newVal)})
    return newdict
```